# How do I create a table of value-frequency combinations arranged vertically in R

Tags: r, frequency

How do I create a table of value-frequency combinations arranged vertically,

```
> df = data.frame(fruit=c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "cherry", "apple", "banana", "apple", "date"));
> table(df$fruit)

 apple banana cherry   date 
     3      2      2      1
```

So far so good. But I'd like something that's like this (e.g. to basic manipulations and subsetting of values based on the frequency):

```
Fruit   Freq
"apple"   3
"banana"  2
"cherry"  2
"date"    1
```

In SQL, that'd be `SELECT fruit, COUNT(*) AS Freq FROM df GROUP BY fruit`, and would yield  a table that's like the starting point to this question:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-to-convert-a-frequency-table-into-a-vector-of-values

Is there an easy way to do that in **R**? (Alternatively, does this indicate a mindset that's too 'SQL' and not enough 'R'?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data.frame(table(df))
#       df Freq
# 1  apple    3
# 2 banana    2
# 3 cherry    2
# 4   date    1
```

Or perhaps

```
setNames(data.frame(table(df)), c("Fruit", "Freq"))
#    Fruit Freq
# 1  apple    3
# 2 banana    2
# 3 cherry    2
# 4   date    1
```

Comment: Wow, three great choices in minute!  The `melt` option works perfect too and the matrix provides a subtly different option as well. Accepting this one just because no package to install.

Answer (score 4):

Using just base R, you can just convert it to a matrix which will be column oriented with the values as the row.names.

```
as.matrix(table(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `melt` function from reshape2 package

```
DF <- table(df$fruit)

library(reshape2)
melt(DF)
colnames(result) <- c('Fruit', 'Freq')
result


  Fruit Freq
1  apple    3
2 banana    2
3 cherry    2
4   date    1
```

Comment: The reshape package is great to learn about, thanks! [http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the SQL mindset, there's always the "`sqldf`" package!

```
df = data.frame(fruit=c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "cherry", 
                        "apple", "banana", "apple", "date"))
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT fruit, COUNT(*) AS Freq FROM df GROUP BY fruit")
#    fruit Freq
# 1  apple    3
# 2 banana    2
# 3 cherry    2
# 4   date    1
```

There! You already knew the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a different answer :

```
df = data.frame(fruit=c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "cherry", "apple", "banana", "apple", "date"));
df
   fruit
1  apple
2 banana
3 cherry
4 cherry
5  apple
6 banana
7  apple
8   date
freq <- unlist(lapply(unique(df$fruit),function(x) length(which(df$fruit ==x))))

freq
[1] 3 2 2 1
df.new <- data.frame(fruits = unique(df$fruit),freq)
df.new
  fruits freq
1  apple    3
2 banana    2
3 cherry    2
4   date    1
```